# Why can't the install location be selected from Browse directory panel in Burn?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

Has anyone come across problems with the Browse for Folder panel under the Option button in the native burn bundle BA?

I have an Edit box that specifies where the install location is. It is set to a default location. Pressing the Browse button launches a directory list (Browse for Folder) for picking another installation location. However, no matter what has been selected, it  doesn’t get populated into the Edit box and so the path remains the default no matter what the users pick. The path inside the Edit box can be manually changed (typed in) but not through Browse.

I would like to get this working because this is the only place for users to specify the install location (I have suppressed the MSI’s UI). If possible, I hope to be done through the native BA.

Is there some WiX tags I should be applying to get this working? What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code which I think is relevant for this issue.

Inside the *Bundle*

```
<Variable Name="INSTALLLOC" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFiles6432Folder]"
   bal:Overridable="yes" />
<util:DirectorySearch
  Variable="INSTALLLOC"
  Path="[ProgramFiles6432Folder]" />
```

Also under *Chain*

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SoftwareMsi)"
   Vital="yes" Visible="yes" DisplayInternalUI="no" >
   <MsiProperty Name="PRODUCTDIR" Value="[INSTALLLOC]" />
</MsiPackage>
```

Also for my theme template

```
<Page Name="Options">
  <Text X="175" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">Destination folder</Text>
  <Text X="175" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="0" DisablePrefix="yes">Select a folder where the application will be installed.</Text>
  <Editbox Name="INSTALLLOC" X="175" Y="143" Width="-91" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" FileSystemAutoComplete="yes"/>
  <Button Name="BrowseButton" X="-11" Y="142" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">
    <Text>Browse</Text>
    <BrowseDirectoryAction VariableName="INSTALLLOC" />
  </Button>
  <Button Name="OptionsOkButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">OK</Button>
  <!-- And other buttons/text -->
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button Name="BrowseButton" X="-11" Y="142" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">
  <Text>Browse</Text>
  <BrowseDirectoryAction VariableName="INSTALLLOC" />
</Button>
```

is WiX v4.x theme syntax but you said in a comment that you're using v3.x.  WiX v3.x had this kind of stuff hardcoded, so you should be basing your theme off of a v3.x theme.  I don't remember whether it's possible to autopopulate the `FolderEditbox` in v3.x.

```
<Editbox Name="FolderEditbox" X="11" Y="143" Width="-91" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" FileSystemAutoComplete="yes" />
<Button Name="BrowseButton" X="-11" Y="142" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">#(loc.OptionsBrowseButton)</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your solution does do the job of getting Browse to populate the Edit box with the selection. However it seemed to break something else.

Comment: I replaced INSTALLLOC with FolderEditbox in the theme file and in the bootstrapper code. Now the Browse button works but the value in the Editbox doesn't get recognised by the installer. It ignores the path in the editbox and just install in the default location. I think its because the path name isn't in CAPS so path doesn't get passed along.  Tried changing FolderEditbox to FOLDEREDITBOX but the Browse button directory broke again but the software does install to the path manually entered into the Edit box.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom bootstrapper application?

In the wixstandardbootstrapperapplication source we see the following:

```
//
// OnClickOptionsBrowseButton - browse for install folder on the options page.
//
void OnClickOptionsBrowseButton()
{
    WCHAR wzPath[MAX_PATH] = { };
    BROWSEINFOW browseInfo = { };
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl = NULL;

    browseInfo.hwndOwner = m_hWnd;
    browseInfo.pszDisplayName = wzPath;
    browseInfo.lpszTitle = m_pTheme->sczCaption;
    browseInfo.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_USENEWUI;
    pidl = ::SHBrowseForFolderW(&browseInfo);
    if (pidl && ::SHGetPathFromIDListW(pidl, wzPath))
    {
        ThemeSetTextControl(m_pTheme, WIXSTDBA_CONTROL_FOLDER_EDITBOX, wzPath);
    }

    if (pidl)
    {
        ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
    }

    return;
}
```

After launching the browse dialog (BROWSEINFOW) it gets the selected path and then updates the text control.

Additionally, when you click 'Back' or 'Next/Install' you need to set the InstallFolder variable to the value in the edit box.

Comment: I am using WiX 3.10.2 binaries as downloaded from CodePlex. I can't see the code you mentioned as almost everything is hidden inside dlls and exes. The only customization I am making are the text layout and file specifics in Burn.